# Use enumerate to count the position of a value in a np array

Tags: python, numpy, probability

I am trying to write a function that returns the median of a distribution P:

[image]

My idea is to use np.median() and then enumerate to get the order or indexing (in this case x). Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: So you want the median and the P(median)? I am confused regarding the enumeration part you talked about.

Comment: can you give us an example?

Comment: Maybe enumerate is not needed at all, just an idea. I want to calculate the median value and get as a result its corresponding "x", i.e. index +1

Comment: For example, if P = [0.1,0.2,0.1,0.3,0.1,0.2] the function should return 4 as the median m is its 4th value, as it satisfies that P(x<=m) >=1/2 and P(x>=m) >=1/2.

Comment: In that case: `P.cumsum().searchsorted(0.5)+1`

Comment: Thanks Paul. Can you please explain how?

Comment: `P.cumsum()` computes cumulative probabilies, i.e. `P(x-1<=index) = P.cumsum()[index]`, `.searchsorte(0.5)` finds the offset at which `P.cumsum()` passes `0.5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Paul, the code I was looking for is:

```
def median_cal(P):
    npa = np.asarray(P, dtype=np.float32)
    a = npa.cumsum().searchsorted(0.5)+1
    return a
```